# Firebase not working with GCM server

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

- **t-0:** Someone has a server X that uses GCM to send notifications on certain events
- **t-1:** I build my android app against server X and implement GCM. And it works great.
- **t-2:** Firebase has a nice feature that lets you send notification from a console (similar to how Facebook's Parse used to work)
- **t-3:** I change from GCM to FCM.
- **t-4:** My android app can no longer receive notifications from server X

[Now Firebase claims, and I quote](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_the_usage_of_gcmpubsub)

> Updating these endpoints is not strictly required, as Google will
>   continue to support the existing GCM endpoints.

For the skeptics: I am working on two different git branches fcm and gcm. When I am on branch gcm notification works; but on fcm I cannot get notification from server X (but it works from the Console, yay!)

Comment: Can you include the changes you made to the manifest when moving to FCM?

Comment: is the FCM app using the same Project / Sender-ID as GCM version of your app? You can either migrate the old project to a "firebase project" from the firebase console, or register the FCM app for a secondary sender via FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("sender2", "FCM")

Comment: I followed the tutorial for migration. (and it's not as complicated as the word "migration" might intimate)

Comment: Could you also add your message handling code to the question, your extension of FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: are you imported your GCM project via FCM console to work with FCM?

Answer (score 0):

**You'll have to continue using the old method you were using to send push notifications to GCM users and for the users who registers through FCM will only be able to receive push notifications through FCM or Firebase Notification console.**

You can't send push notification to GCM registration tokens through FCM.